# SQL server 2012 jdbc driver for jdk 1.4

Tags: java, sqljdbc

I need SQL server jdbc driver jar file which is compatible with jdk1.4 and sql server 2012.

I am using sqljdbc3 which is not compatible with jdk1.4 and jboss 4.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe sql server does NOT provide support for jdk/jre 1.4. Here is the content from the [msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx):

> sqljdbc.jar class library requires a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) of
>   version 5.0. Using sqljdbc.jar on JRE 6.0 or JRE 7.0 will throw an
>   exception when connecting to a database.
>
> **Note** **The JDBC Driver does not support JRE 1.4**. You must
>   upgrade JRE 1.4 to JRE 5.0, JRE 6.0, or JRE 7.0 when using the JDBC
>   Driver. In some cases, you might need to recompile your application
>   because it might not be compatible with JDK 5.0 API or JDK 6.0 API.
>   For more information, see the documentation on Sun Microsystems Web
>   site. Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server does not support JDK 7.